# Are GNOME extensions OS dependent?

Tags: gnome, system, gnome-shell-extension

Pretty straight question: are all GNOME extensions available for any OS?

I thought that the only thing needed is the Gnome desktop environment, but [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631897/cpu-and-memory-usage-monitor-gnome-extension) has been put on hold because I'm currently using Arch Linux and is not Ubuntu-related.

I read the [Gnome extension FAQs](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/) but they don't seem to explain this doubt I have.

I understand that not all GNOME extension are available for all GNOME versions, but can they work on different Operative Systems in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome extensions solely rely on GNOME, as long as they do not make use of OS-dependent features, e.g. an extension using pacman does't work on Debian- and RedHat-based systems.

---

Your other question was closed as off-topic because **this Q&A site** is about Ubuntu only. If you're having a GNOME-related problem with your Arch system, the Arch forums may be better suited for you, even if the problem could be reproduced on Ubuntu, too. Or you can ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

50% of answers I find to problems with my Ubuntu or Mint come from the Arch forums, so there clearly can be an intersection of answers.

Comment: I completely agree with you (especially for the edited part :P). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DarioSalvati I edited out the opinionated part (another site policy). For discussing that we have [meta], so it's nice to limit the amount in the real answers.

Comment: Yes, now I understand the site policy. Even if I don't agree on certain points I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [GNOME Shell - About](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/)

> ### What are GNOME Shell Extensions?
>
> GNOME Shell extensions are small pieces of code written by third party developers that modify the way GNOME works. (If you are familiar with Chrome Extensions or Firefox Addons, GNOME Shell extensions are similar to them.) You can find and install GNOME Shell extensions using this website.
>
> ### I'm using GNOME 3. Why can't I install extensions?
>
> Some distributions don't quite package GNOME correctly. Make sure that you have the unzip package installed.

[Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Extensions)

> The catalogue of extensions is available at extensions.gnome.org. By a user they can be installed and activated in the browser by setting the switch in the top left of the screen to ON and clicking Install on the resulting dialog (if the extension in question is not installed). After installation it is shown in the extensions.gnome.org/local/ tab, which has to be visited as well to check for available updates. Installed extensions can also be enabled or disabled using gnome-tweak-tool.
>
> Installing extensions via a package makes them available for all users of the system and automates the update process.

So they should work for you. If you still have trouble, please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/) - your questions will be welcomed there.

Comment: That's okay :-)